# Alternate for updating record

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have temporary table in which I have set a column as FLAG with value '0'.
I am using a cursor in stored procedure, where in the column named FLAG gets updated as '1' as loop executes for 3 three times.

The task is that "the FLAG updated as 1 should not remain in temp table as 1".  However, since its a temp table, the values cannot remain the same.

Can anyone help me out for the same,

Comment: can you give me sample data or example of your doing. and what do you mean by this `The task is that"the FLAG updated as 1 should not remain in temp table as 1."..but since its a temp table ,the values cannot remain the sam`

Comment: @Moudiz-The primary task of this stored procedure is to send mail.This job will be executing many times in a day.Hence it is to make sure that the user once received with mail should be sent again.And the hence the record updated as 1 should not receive the mail

Comment: Then why are you storing this information in a temp table instead of a permanent one?

Comment: SInce the number of columns are fixed in permanent table and it cannot be modified.

Comment: What you can do, you can keep all updated records in separated temp table and once your mailing task done update your permanent table with separated records which is keeping the flagged records

Comment: I don't know why somebody marked this question up. As posted it just doesn't have anywhere near enough information to be a valid question.

Comment: @Rahul Neekhra-I had Implemented the same Logic.But if i update temp table with column name FLAG as 1.and when the batch executes again ,the temp table wont be with the value 1 as it would have lost its existence.